# How to reset Running total in Google Sheets when MOQ is reached?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

Please provide an array formula. Can you help to reset running totals when MOQ is reached?. Here MOQ=15. When running total becomes equal to or greater than 15 it should restart.

| Date | Value | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/2022 | 6 | 6 |
| 01/2023 | 5 | 11 |
| 02/2023 | 4 | 15 |
| 03/2023 | 3 | 3 |
| 04/2023 | 9 | 12 |
| 05/2023 | 2 | 14 |
| 06/2023 | 6 | 20 |
| 07/2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 08/2023 | 6 | 7 |
| 09/2023 | 1 | 8 |
| 10/2023 | 8 | 16 |
| 11/2023 | 9 | 9 |
| 12/2023 | 3 | 12 |

Answer (score 1):

all we need is a unique common ID for grouping the sum. we start with months to fall from whatever date to months 3, 7 and 11:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2:A), {3;7;11}, 1, 1), 11))
```

[image]

next, we can use years to differentiate between 11/2022 and 11/2023 so we take whatever date and convert it into first day of given month and then offset the year by 58 days:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(EOMONTH(A2:A, -1)+1-58))
```

[image]

we combine it to get a unique ID per MOQ:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2:A), {3;7;11}, 1, 1), 11)&
 " "&YEAR(EOMONTH(A2:A, -1)+1-58)))
```

[image]

then we just use standard running total fx:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))>=ROW(A2:A))*(
 IFERROR(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2:A), {3;7;11}, 1, 1), 11)&"×"&
 YEAR(EOMONTH(A2:A, -1)+1-58))=TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2:A), {3;7;11}, 1, 1), 11)&"×"&
 YEAR(EOMONTH(A2:A, -1)+1-58)))), B2:B, 0)), ROW(A2:A)^0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",, MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B))>=ROW(B2:B))*(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({0; IF(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15)>
 MAX(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))-1, 
 MAX(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))-1,
     TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))}, ROWS(B2:B), 1)=TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({0; IF(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15)>
 MAX(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))-1, 
 MAX(TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))-1,
     TRUNC(SUMIF(ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B), B2:B)/15))}, ROWS(B2:B), 1))), B2:B, 0)), 
 ROW(B2:B)^0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Why you take the date column into acount? can you use the value column only? reset the count if sum >=15.

Comment: @Osm yeah about that, because I didn't understand the question properly :D I was treating it like "running total for year divided into three equal quarters" where it resets every March, July and November. now I see I may get it wrong by googling MOQ where it stands for "minimal order quantity" not "monthly original quarters" or whatever I thought it is lol

Comment: You can replace MOQ in this case 15 with cell refrence to be able to change it in the future.

Comment: Player0, I believe that using just the most recent update and highlighting the editing process in the [Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73635001/timeline) would make the response clearer. thanks for the answer can't upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new `SCAN` function

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B, LAMBDA(a,c, IF(c="",,IF(a>=15,c,a+c))))
```

What we did is: return the running total of Values if less than or equal 15, else rest.

[image]

**Explation**

`SCAN` Takes initial_value we set it to `0` and array_or_range we name it `c` "Current value" for short, and the accumulator in lambda `a` you can name them any thing.

IF the accumulator `a` is greater or equal 15 `>= 15` then reset by returning the Current value of array_or_range `c`, if not add the current value of array_or_range `c` to the accumulator `a`.

Used formulas help
[**`SCAN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)